# CSS class won't override border-style

Tags: css, colors, border

I have styled all my text fields with a gray border, and for the fields with `class="form_field_error"`, I want the border-color to change to red.

I have tried the following code, but I can't get my class to override the previously defined border? What am I missing?

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form_field_error">
```

CSS:

```css
input[type="text"] {
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #777;
    padding: 3px;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.form_field_error {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zYB6x/) to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.form_field_error {
    border: 1px solid #f00 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `input[type="text"]` css takes precedence over the `.form_field_error` css.

Change it to `input.form_field_error` and the border will work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using:

```
input[type="text"].form_field_error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The "!important" rule should only be used as a last resort - nuclear option - because it will surpass all other attempts to target an element based on precise and relevant specificity, reducing the control you have and creating potential roadblocks for future developers. Therefore the proper way, and the best way to handle it is to start with the same selector as the original one you are trying to override, then simply add the one thing that distinguishes it from the original. This way the specificity will be precisely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying which div to apply the red border to like this?

```css
 input.form_field_error {
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

And on a side note - the ID you set as 'title' is that just for that one or are you thinking of reusing that?

Because you could also do ->

```css
#title.form_field_error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```